# Find index of number in array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting, comparison-operators

I have got this issue where I want to return the index of the number in the array which is smaller the one before it. For eg. in this array [6, 8, 10, 2, 4], I want the function to return 3 (which is the index of 2 where 2 < 10). I have used a for loop to iterate over each number and compare it with index - 1 but am unable to output the correct answer. Below is my code:

```
// 1
function rotateNum(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[i - 1]) {
            return i;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

console.log(rotateNum([5, 4, 3, 1, 2]));
console.log(rotateNum([2, 3, 4, 5, 1]));
console.log(rotateNum([6, 8, 12, 1, 3]));
console.log(rotateNum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Please let me know where am I doing it wrong. Javascript.

Comment: too early return of index zero. move this tatement to the end of the function and better return `-1`, because this is usual for not found indices, like `indexOf`. more [info](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/the-return-early-pattern-explained-with-javascript-examples/19364) (couldnt find dupe, but exists)

Comment: `return` immediately exits the function and returns the value. And you call `return` in both cases

Comment: You should start your loop at `i = 1`. Otherwise `arr[i-1]` accesses outside the array.

Comment: What is your desired result if multiple elements meet that condition? Like in your example `[5,4,3,1,2]`? Return only the first index (ie `1`) or return all of them (ie `[1,2,3]`),

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***It's very simple. First apply Math.min method and spread your array and easily get smallest number.Then you can find the index of smallest number in array by indexOf method.***
*Here is the code:*

```
const rotateNum = array => {
    const small = Math.min(...array)
    return array.indexOf(small)
}
```

Comment: This will return `3` for the first example,`[5,4,3,1,2]` whereas the desired answer is `1`

Comment: And there are better methods for finding the index of the minimum element with out the need of traversing the array twice ...

Answer (score -1):

```
function rotateNum(arr) {
  const minVal = Math.min(...arr);
  const index = arr.findIndex(v => v === minVal);
  return index;
}
```

here, first i found out min value of an array and then using array findIndex method we got the index

Comment: This will return `3` for the first example,`[5,4,3,1,2]` whereas the desired answer is `1`

Comment: As per my understanding, here we have to find the index of smallest number. But i think as per above comment we have to find index of small number which comes after the largest number

Answer (score -1):

here you go mate:

```
function rotateNum(arr) {
  for (x in arr) {
  arr[x] < arr[x - 1] ? console.log(arr.indexOf(arr[x - 1]) +1) : {};
 }}
```

Comment: As `x` will start with `0`, `arr[x-1]` will be out of bounds. Fuhrtermore, `arr.indexOf(arr[x - 1])` makes no sense, as -- at least in this context -- it will always return`x-1`. And you are missing a `}`

Comment: did you try testing it?

Comment: Yes, I did. It prints out `0`, `1`, and `2`.  `0` is wrong in this output, because according to OP's requirements index `0` can never be part of the result, because the number at index `0` definitively is not smaller than the number before it (because there is no number before it).

Comment: But that's not the point of my comment. The point was that `arr.indexOf(arr[x - 1])` does unecessary work searching the array, because in an array of unique values it will always return `x-1`, you can know that without seaching. And in an array like `[1,2,3,4,1,2,3]` it will wrongly return `0` when the desired index is actually `4`

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to say here but even with your given test case code seems to be working just fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/fk4c731o/2/

Comment: My point is that in an array with distinct elements the result of `arr.indexOf(arr[x-1])` will per definition **always** be `x-1` so there is no need for calling `arr.indexOf`. And if your array does not have distinct elements, it can give wrong results. Try `[1,2,3,4,4,1,2,3]` The expected output is `5` but your algorithm produces `4`.

Comment: thanks man! I see it now. :) Appreciate the help!